# jquery remove element if it occurs twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like this in my html:

```
<div class="onlyContent">
    <!-- some more stuff here -->
</div>
<div class="onlyContent">
    <!-- some more stuff here -->
</div>
```

Now, with `jQuery` I want to remove the 2nd occurence of the class `onlyContent` HTML from the dom.

The final result should be this:

```
<div class="onlyContent">
    <!-- some more stuff here -->
</div>
```

I figured out that you can somehow use the `nth-child`-selector, but trying to access it this way didn't do it for me

```
$('.onlyContent:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

Comment: you code is working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bptwLzh/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:eq(1)` for targetting second element in matched set:

```
$('.onlyContent:eq(1)').remove();
```

If the number of elements more than two, then you should use `:not(:first)` or `:gt(0)`:

```
$('.onlyContent:not(:first)').remove();
```

or

```
$('.onlyContent:gt(0)').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

use below code . use jQuery [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector.

> Select the element at index n within the matched set.

check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/utas8svq/2/)

```
   $('.onlyContent:eq(1)').remove();
```

Comment: The check is quite superflu

Comment: When jquery methods are capable of handling themselves.

Comment: @A.Wolff  answer updated. i thought it gives `undefined` if not element available

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
$('.onlyContent:gt(0)').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
   $('.onlyContent:gt(0)').remove();
```

It will remove all the duplicates. Only the first one will be present.

Comment: The check is quite superflu

Comment: @A.Wolff Right. there is no need of that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.slice` for this.

```
$(".onlyContent").slice(1).remove();
```

Nice and simple, no fuss. [Working example](http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/yNabPg).

From the `.slice` documentation:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of
>   indices

You can find more [here](https://api.jquery.com/slice/).

Answer (score 0):

Use .length property to check the numbers of selected elements on the page and if its value is greater than 1 then remove the elements other than first...

```
if($('.onlyContent').length > 1) {
$('.onlyContent:gt(0)').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$(".onlyContent").not(':first').remove();
```