# I Need A Better Way To Hide A Subset Of Elements Of The Same Class In JQuery

Tags: jquery

My DOM has over 50 instances of a class. I want to hide a subset.

What is the best way to do this? A one line Lambda function?

I do not want to do:

```
$('.my-class').eq(10).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(11).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(12).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(13).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(14).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(15).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(16).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(17).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(18).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(19).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(20).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(21).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(22).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(23).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(24).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(25).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(26).hide();
$('.my-class').eq(27).hide();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do those `eq` numbers ever change, or are they static to 10 to 27?

Comment: jQuery has a `slice()` method.  https://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: You might want to try something like this $('.my-class').slice(2, 14).hide();

Comment: This question looks somewhat related and you might get ideas from it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371831/jquery-remove-element-if-it-occurs-twice

Comment: try `for` cycle

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Taplar and quantumPuter!!

It looks like the "slice" method is the way to go.

$('.my-class').slice( 10, 27 ).hide();

I appreciate all the help.